# How can I make a console application that lets me enter LINQ expressions and my program will execute them?

Tags: c#, linq, console, parsing

How can I write a console application that prompts me and lets me enter LINQ expressions and it will spit out the results of that LINQ query?

What would be the easiest way to parse/evaluate a incoming string as a LINQ expression?

Answer (score 2):

Console app is to awkward to use for thousands of reasons. Try [LinqPad](http://www.linqpad.net/)

Comment: This is functionality I'm looking to add to an existing application.  I know about LinqPad

Answer (score 1):

use Dynamic LINQ query library , see [this](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/01/07/dynamic-linq-part-1-using-the-linq-dynamic-query-library.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

I wrote [LinqFilter](http://bittwiddlers.org/?p=141) for something similar to this purpose. It does no parsing of LINQ query expressions on its own, but rather sends the code off to the C# v3.5 compiler via Microsoft.CSharp.CSharpCodeProvider to compile into a dynamic assembly and executes the compiled method containing the query. If you were looking for a more interactive approach to designing LINQ queries over databases, LinqPad would be the better tool.